# SoapObject result of service call is always null

Tags: android, google-app-engine, soap, wsdl, ksoap2

I have implemented my SOAP webservice following the tutorial found on google developers website, and now i'm writing a android app that call an available service and show result (for now in a textview) using ksoap2 libraries.
That's the code:

```
public class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject> {
private static String METHOD_NAME = "getData";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.com/getData";
private static String WSDL_URL = "http://arduino-data-server.appspot.com/FunctionsService.wsdl";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://example.com/";
private MainActivity caller_activity;

public DownloadDataTask(MainActivity a) {
    caller_activity = a;
}

@Override
protected SoapObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result) {
    TextView tw = (TextView) caller_activity.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    if (result == null) {
        tw.setText("NULL");
    } else {
        tw.setText(result.getName());
    }
}
}
```

but everytime, the result SoapObject it's null. what's wrong? on appengine server log, i can see that android app ask for wsdl file, but no request for service was sent. What's wrong (wsdl file is available ad url write inside my code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ksoap doesn't use wsdl (and so doesn't request it). You should pass service url instead of wsdl url. Service url you can find in wsdl (attribute `location` of the `address` element in the service description section).

Comment: ok, thanks. So the ksoap2 tutorial that i follow was wrong.. It told me to add wsdl url, not the service url

Comment: But problem still remain, always null were returned by webservice. Maybe i'm wrong with something while create soap envelope?

Comment: Why are you using `SoapEnvelope.VER12`? Wsdl contains definition for 1.1 version only. Try to change this to `SoapEnvelope.VER11`.

Comment: Also probably you get an exception rather than null returned by webservice.

Comment: And the last thing: `envelope.getResponse()` can return `SoapFault`, `PropertyInfo`, `SoapObject` or even `Vector`. In your case it should return `Vector` of SoapObjects, so this  `(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()` will throw class cast exception.

Comment: Thank you. You was very useful and very clear on explanation, and you save me a lot of time without found any solution